# What Python exception does 'OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use' cause

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a basic Python TCP socket server. I want to catch the specific exception listed above, what do I need to put after `except` to do that?

Comment: Why not simply do something to cause the error, and see what Exception is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the OSError, so you need to catch OSError:

```py
except OSError as error:
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that there is an existing process using the same ip address and port that you're using within your code.

To answer your initial question, this is how you would handle this exception in Python:

```
try :
    #your code here 
except OSError as error :
    print(error)
```

Nevertheless, this will not solve your issue, and it doesn't make much sense to catch the error (only if you want to exit gracefully and show a message maybe). You just need to find the process which is using the same address in your task manager and kill it.